# Potential risks or TBD?

Tags: project-management-style

As a project manager, is it a good idea to replace potential risks with 'to be determined' (TBD) as a placeholder in a project guide?

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient information to answer the question.  I'm not sure what a "project guide" is, or what role it plays, and I'm not sure what the difference is between a "potential risk" and a "risk". Most important however is that I don't know *why* someone is indicating that the risk is "TBD".

If you use TBD as a short term placeholder until you can gather the right people to do the analysis, that is fine.

If, on the other hand, the analysis is never done, if there are risks in the registry that haven't been analyzed in weeks, then there is a problem. That tells me that risk assessment/analysis isn't being performed, and that is very much a problem.

The problem is whether you're doing effective risk management or not; "TBD" can be a symptom or indicator of weak risk assessment.  The real question is whether your risk management *as you perform it* is reducing risk.

Answer (score 0):

In some risk literature, there's a definition for a "hazard", which means a condition that would become a threat if the hazard would be put in play.  For example, flying in a plane has inherent hazards that can be quantitatively measured.  It is not a threat to you until you board the plane and until the plane begins its take off roll.  Up to that point, it is only a hazard.

In a project sense, as a management team is trying to determine which project to undertake, the lists of risks are really hazards, or potential risks, that would be come risks when the project is selected and begins.  Assuming the OP means this, then capturing potential risks, or hazards, is a must do.  Capturing it as TBD is a waste of time and shows a lack of analysis and initiative, unless it is used as a VERY temporary indicator to show the rest of the analysis will start ASAP.  A potential risk or risks should be well thought out, analyzed, quantified where you can, and with potential mitigation strategies.

This type of project risk would be captured in a project's business case.

For a project that has already started, a potential risk, or hazard, would be a secondary risk created due to a mitigation action of a primary risk.  Capturing the secondary risk would be done as part of the documentation of the primary risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use TBD as a placeholder, make sure you have a clear list of the TBS's and a plan (schedule + owners) of how to replace them with real data, real soon.